# GROUP BY within functions

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently stuck with MySQL

```
SELECT 
  c.id_customer, 
  ROUND(SUM((o.commision_main + o.commision_delivery)/(
    SELECT COUNT(o.id_order)
    FROM orders AS o 
    INNER JOIN customers AS c 
      ON o.id_customer = c.id_customer 
    GROUP BY)), 2) AS profit 
FROM orders AS o 
INNER JOIN customers AS c 
  ON o.id_customer = c.id_customer 
GROUP BY c.id_customer
```

I would love to make this SQL to use the COUNT for each id_customer that was GROUP BYed as well.
[Picture of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W21IR.png) 
And now it takes COUNT for every id_customer so it divides everything by 6 instead of 3 for id_customer 3, 2 for id_customer 1 and 1 for id_customer 66.
Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your query seems needlessly complex, I am pretty sure you can get the result you are after with simply `SELECT o.id_customer, ROUND(AVG(o.commision_main + o.commision_delivery) , 2) AS Profit FROM Orders AS o GROUP BY o.id_customer;`

Comment: @GarethD Thank you very much!!! Can you make your comment an answer? So I can make this as solve? Thanks for helping tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems needlessly complex, I am pretty sure you can get the result you are after with simply

```
SELECT  o.id_customer, 
        ROUND(AVG(o.commision_main + o.commision_delivery) , 2) AS Profit 
FROM    Orders AS o 
GROUP BY o.id_customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the subquery for count() and use count() directly in main query

```
SELECT 
  c.id_customer, 
  ROUND(SUM((o.commision_main + o.commision_delivery)/COUNT(o.id_order)), 2) AS profit 
FROM orders AS o 
INNER JOIN customers AS c  ON o.id_customer = c.id_customer 
GROUP BY c.id_customer
```